# How to implement different layouts of view with different aspect ratio?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a `UIView` called "canvasView" and adding stickers, text, and photos to that view. Suppose if an application changes the layout or size of "canvasView" then how to adjust the position and size of all subviews.

Refer this below image for more details.

[image]

Comment: How would you like your view to change when the size changes?

Comment: View should fit into new aspect ratio including its subviews.

Comment: Are you using storyboard or adding the elements from code?

Comment: Adding elements from code without using auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it is to separate creation of the sub-views and their sizing and placements. In your `canvasView` class you can create the sub-views in one of the `init` functions, for example. Then you do the actual sizing and placements in the `layoutSubviews`. This will be called whenever your view has changed in size, including initially when created.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // position and size each sub-view here
    // self.bounds.size contains your new view size
    // Your sub-views should already be created when coming here since this function is called multiple times

    // You can get your sub-views either by storing them as properties in `canvasView` like this
    self.oneoneButton.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, self.bounds.size.height / 2, 40.0, 40.0);

    // or simply set a unique `tag` on each and find them by calling `[self viewWithTag:xxx]`
    UIView *v = [self viewWithTag:101]; // 101 is the id for 1:1 button
    v.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, self.bounds.size.height / 2, 40.0, 40.0);
}
```